# Simple hashing/checksum function for message acknowledgment between two radio units

Tags: c, hash, checksum

I am trying to setup communications between a pair of Xbee radios with micro controllers. These radios have their own built in acknowledge and checksum functions but they are too simplistic and I still end up with incorrect messages out the other end anyways.

I want to implement a more robust acknowledgment scheme in which the receiver sends a message containing a hash/checksum of the message and the sender looks up that value in a table of sent messages and clears the matching sent message (if a message has not been cleared for a set period of time, the message is resent until a match is found).

My problem is I'm not familiar with checksums and hashing functions, both of which are similar but designed for different purposes.

Is there a simple algorithm that would work well as both a hashing function (collision avoidance so that we don't clear the wrong sent message) and a checksum function (highly sensitive to transmission errors) at the same time that could be simply implemented on an 8-bit micro controller (programmed in C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). Depending on the length you choose, you should be able to calculate it quickly enough on your microcontroller.

If I were you, I wouldn't use the checksum to identify your data packets. I would use an incrementing packet ID for this purpose. This will give you better control and should make it simpler to implement a [sliding window protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a 16-bit CRC, pick some standard polynomial.  That will give you plenty of protection from corruption.  Also, you might add a header with sequence number to detect duplicates if you're doing a reliable retransmission scheme.